# How do you (can you?) boot an installation image from a harddrive partition?

Tags: linux, boot, partition, uefi, iso

I wanted to make a reinstall of my linux mint, but I only have an SD-card and my current installation (which seems to be a UEFI installation based on the occurence of `boot/efi`).

I tried using the `dd` command to put the ISO on my SD-card, but it doesn't show up in my bios and I can't mark it with the boot-flag in gparted.

The best thing would be if I could just keep a bootable partition on the same harddrive that contains the installation ISO for linux mint. I tried the same `dd` command and marked it as bootable in gparted, but it didn't show up. I'm guessing that I haven't made it work for UEFI, but I am pretty sure I don't understand the full picture also.

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: A more common way to do this would be to get a USB and put linux mint on the USB. Then you can always boot from the USB if you need to reinstall.

Comment: Two thoughts: 1. Linux doesn't used boot flags but if it did it should be in the ESP (EFI System Partition), not in the main system partition (you cloned the whole drive, didn't you?). And 2. your computer may not be able to boot from SD cards.